# d3 heatmap column headers as yaxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pivot

I have a dataset like this:

```
CT, CA, GA, TX, Year, Month
1, 1, 2, 4, 2016, 03
2, 1, 3, 5, 2016, 03
```

The numbers under the state columns corresponds to the number of occurrences. 
And I loaded the data into d3, but how can I reorganize the data to be just 4 columns, like this:

```
state, count, year, month
CT, 1, 2016, 03
```

Here's what I have got so far:

```
d3.csv("states.csv", function(error, Data){

            Data.forEach(function(d){
                d.CT = +d.CT;
                d.CA = +d.CA;
                d.GA = +d.GA;
                d.TX = +d.TX;
                d.Year = +d.Year;
                d.month = +d.month;

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your desired output array correctly, this combination of `forEach` and `for...in` can create it:

```js
var csv = `CT,CA,GA,TX,Year,Month
1,1,2,4,2016,03
2,1,3,5,2016,03`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var newData = [];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var key in d) {
    if (key != "Year" && key != "Month") {
      newData.push({
        state: key,
        count: d[key],
        year: d.Year,
        month: d.Month
      })
    }
  }
});

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Since I cannot load a real CSV in the stack snippet I'm storing your example dataset in a variable and parsing it using `d3.csvParse`. However, the principle is the same: just put that function inside the `d3.csv` callback.

**PS**: Based on your example of desired output...

```
state, count, year, month
CT, 1, 2016, 03
```

... I'm assuming that you **don't want** to sum objects with the same year and month. In case you actually do want to sum them, please post another question asking how to do it (or do a search, since that is a common issue, already answered).

Comment: thanks! I loaded in my data and checked the log, it's showing an empty array in the console. it also says newData[0] is undefined when I try to display it. is there something different need to be done in the .push function?

Comment: Well, I have to see the exact code. Setup a Plunker or a Blockbuilder with the code and the CSV.

Comment: `d3.csv` is **asynchronous**. Put the console.log inside the callback.

Comment: btw is there a way to make "count", "year", "month" to be numeric instead of in quotations?

Comment: okay i solved it, i just added "+" in front of d.year to make it a number